# Reportviewer control loading indicator in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, reporting-services, reportviewer

I was just skinning my site with new theme, is it possible to change the loading image (which has green color) of the ReportViewer control?

I tried some solutions suggested but its not working, can anyone guide me on this?
[image]

Comment: These are embeded inside the reportviewer dll i believe. Sadly, i don't know any easy method to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always modify it with CSS.

If you investigate the HTML which is rendered from the ReportViewer control, there should be a `<div>` called `[ID_of_control]_AsyncWait_Wait`

On mine, I have the css;

```
<style>
    /* this will remove the spinner */
    div#ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait img{ display: none; } 
    /* this allows you to modify the td that contains the spinner */
    div#ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait table tbody tr td:first-child{ background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; } 
</style>
```

All you need to do is set the `background-image` on `div#ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait table tbody tr td:first-child` in order to have your own custom image.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution achieves a replacement loading image using jQuery and CSS. Environment is Visual Studio 2013, ReportViewer 10.0, .NET 4.0.

The technique uses **window.setInterval** to replace the loading image *and keep it replaced*. In some instances, such as selecting cascading parameters, the ReportViewer replaces much of its DOM contents, including the loading image. So, simple solutions using a CSS background-image or a one-time replacement of the loading image using jQuery do not work.

Given a ReportViewer control added to a .ASCX user control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<%-- replace stock SSRS wait control ("green spinner") with our own; execute every 200 milliseconds --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    OurApp.timeoutID = window.setInterval(OurApp.reportViewerWaitControlSubstitute, 200);
});
</script>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvc0" runat="server" ... CssClass="ReportViewerControl" ... >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

JavaScript:

```
var OurApp= OurApp|| {};

OurApp.reportViewerWaitControlSubstitute = function () {
    var control = $('.ReportViewerControl div[id$="_AsyncWait_Wait"] img');
    var source = control.attr("src");
    var path = "/media/images/atom.gif";
    var style = "height:48px;width:48px;border-radius:10px;margin-right:10px";
    //don't replace if already our image, or it will not animate
    if (source && (source != path)) {
        control.attr("src", path);
        control.attr("style", style);
    }
}
```

CSS (for rounded corners and a more even arrangement of image and text):

```
.ReportViewerControl div[id$='_AsyncWait_Wait'] {
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:15px 15px 0 !important}
```

The result:

[image: SQL Server Reporting Services ReportViewer custom loading image]

The particular .gif is of an animated atom, and looks very cool when ReportViewer elements are loading!