# Override Asp.net ReportViewer toolbar pagination event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, reportviewer

How to override the  pagination click event of the Asp.net ReportViewer toolbar using jQuery or JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Following answer defines a style class that targets controls with ID.

```
    <style>
        /* this will remove the spinner */
        div#ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait img{ display: none; } 
        /* this allows you to modify the td that contains the spinner */
        div#ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait table tbody tr td:first-child{ background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; } 
    </style>
```

[Reportviewer control loading indicator in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784737/reportviewer-control-loading-indicator-in-asp-net)

I'm still looking for other solutions, i will add them if i found any.